# ansible: Invalid data passed to 'loop'

Tags: ansible

I have this following playbook, which gather facts in google cloud and filter instance names we want.

```
  tasks:
    - name: get tags
      delegate_to: localhost
      gcp_compute_instance_info:
        auth_kind: serviceaccount
        service_account_file: "xxx"
        zone: "xxx"
        filters:
        - "name:{{ names }}*"
        project: "{{ project }}"
      register: ilist

    - name: Display output
      debug: var=ilist['items']

    - set_fact:
        instances: "{{ instances|default([]) + [ item.name ] }}"
      loop: "{{ ilist['items']}}"
      when: item.name is regex(".*"+tag+"-[a-z0-9]{4}$")

    - debug:
        var: instances
```

I'm getting following error in the loop task

> Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead:
> <built-in method items of dict object at 0x7fe0f370aa70>. Hint: If you
> passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to
> your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup.

what I'm doing wrong here? thanks

and this is the output of ilist

```
{
   "changed":false,
   "failed":false,
   "resources":[
      {
         "canIpForward":false,
         "cpuPlatform":"Intel Haswell",
         "creationTimestamp":"2020-09-14T04:05:58.316-07:00",
         "deletionProtection":false,
         "disks":[
            {
               "autoDelete":true,
               "boot":true,
               "deviceName":"persistent-disk-0",
               "diskSizeGb":"10",
               "guestOsFeatures":[
                  {
                     "type":"VIRTIO_SCSI_MULTIQUEUE"
                  }
               ],
               "index":0,
               "interface":"SCSI",
               "kind":"compute#attachedDisk",
               "licenses":[
                  "xxxx"
               ],
               "mode":"READ_WRITE",
               "source":"xxxx",
               "type":"PERSISTENT"
            }
         ],
         "fingerprint":"3yOdLl6Hp8g=",
         "id":"3503717950118097018",
         "kind":"compute#instance",
         "labelFingerprint":"IP52FxBvsW0=",
         "labels":{
            "block":"internal",
            "component":"dev",
            "function":"internal"
         },
         "lastStartTimestamp":"2020-09-14T04:06:26.016-07:00",
         "machineType":"xxxx",
         "metadata":{
            "fingerprint":"sTp1wPeotCo=",
            "items":[
               {
                  "key":"instance-template",
                  "value":"xxxx
               },
               {
                  "key":"created-by",
                  "value":"xxxx"
               }
            ],
            "kind":"compute#metadata"
         },
         "name":"test-vm",
         "networkInterfaces":[
            {
               "fingerprint":"ae26IqBpxVo=",
               "kind":"compute#networkInterface",
               "name":"nic0",
               "network":"xxxx",
               "networkIP":"xxxx"
            }
         ],
         "scheduling":{
            "automaticRestart":true,
            "onHostMaintenance":"MIGRATE",
            "preemptible":false
         },
         "selfLink":"xxxxx",
         "serviceAccounts":[
            {
               "email":"xxxx",
               "scopes":[
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "startRestricted":false,
         "status":"RUNNING",
         "tags":{
            "fingerprint":"Oyf1u-BGqNA=",
            "items":[
               "no-ip-b"
            ]
         },
         "zone":"xxxx"
      },
      {
         "canIpForward":false,
         "cpuPlatform":"Intel Haswell",
         "creationTimestamp":"2020-10-15T06:59:52.505-07:00",
         "deletionProtection":false,
         "disks":[
            {
               "autoDelete":true,
               "boot":true,
               "deviceName":"persistent-disk-0",
               "diskSizeGb":"10",
               "guestOsFeatures":[
                  {
                     "type":"VIRTIO_SCSI_MULTIQUEUE"
                  }
               ],
               "index":0,
               "interface":"SCSI",
               "kind":"compute#attachedDisk",
               "licenses":[
                  "xxxx"
               ],
               "mode":"READ_WRITE",
               "source":"xxxxx",
               "type":"PERSISTENT"
            }
         ],
         "fingerprint":"-E0UpLFggow=",
         "id":"5900118287465179960",
         "kind":"compute#instance",
         "labelFingerprint":"IP52FxBvsW0=",
         "labels":{
            "block":"internal",
            "component":"dev",
            "function":"internal"
         },
         "lastStartTimestamp":"2020-10-15T07:00:37.895-07:00",
         "machineType":"xxxxx",
         "metadata":{
            "fingerprint":"05Oj3Bq6zb4=",
            "items":[
               {
                  "key":"instance-template",
                  "value":"xxxx"
               },
               {
                  "key":"created-by",
                  "value":"xxxx"
               }
            ],
            "kind":"compute#metadata"
         },
         "name":"test-vm",
         "networkInterfaces":[
            {
               "fingerprint":"H24HFGkCFNg=",
               "kind":"compute#networkInterface",
               "name":"nic0",
               "network":"xxxx",
               "networkIP":"xxxx"
            }
         ],
         "scheduling":{
            "automaticRestart":true,
            "onHostMaintenance":"MIGRATE",
            "preemptible":false
         },
         "selfLink":"xxxx",
         "serviceAccounts":[
            {
               "email":"xxxx",
               "scopes":[
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "startRestricted":false,
         "status":"RUNNING",
         "tags":{
            "fingerprint":"Oyf1u-BGqNA=",
            "items":[
               "no-ip-b"
            ]
         },
         "zone":"xxxx"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: You question is missing a run of your playbook with a view of the debugged original data.

Comment: @Zeitounator I added the output of ilist

Comment: There is no element 'items' in 'ilist', but I see one called 'ressources' which contains a list of dicts...

Answer (score -1):

You can try with the query function

`loop: {{ query('dict', ilist.items) }}`

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'dict'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: with_dict expects a dict